# Customize a View 3 SQL query

Tags: 7, views

I've created a view that lists the content based on the first letter of that title matching an argument passed to the page. Now I'm trying to do the same, but with a `0-9` so when the user selects `0-9` the view gets all content types which begin with a number in the range `0-9`.

I'm currently looking at `hook_views_query_alter()`, but I don't get back the results I am expecting. The function I've written is the following one:

```
function module_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
  if ($view->name == 'custom_page' && $view->current_display == 'page_1') {
    if ($view->args[0] == '0-9') {
      $query->where[0]['conditions'][2]['field'] = 'SUBSTRING(node.title, 1, 1)';
      $query->where[0]['conditions'][2]['value'] = array('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9');
      $query->where[0]['conditions'][2]['operator'] = 'in';
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bit of a cheat following the code that's used by the glossary view, but it works:

```
function module_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
  if ($view->name == 'custom_page' && $view->current_display == 'page_1') {
    if ($view->args[0] == '0-9') {
      $query->where[0]['conditions'][2]['field'] =  "SUBSTRING(node.title, 1, :node_title) in ('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9')";
      $query->where[0]['conditions'][2]['value'] = array(':node_title' => 1);
      $query->where[0]['conditions'][2]['operator'] = 'formula';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, when using the [in()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) operator, you must past the list in a certain format. I'm not sure that views automatically converts PHP arrays to that format or not.

I know that when I've used [in()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) in the past, I converted arrays myself. In your case it would look like this:

```
$query->where[0]['conditions'][2]['value'] = "('" . implode("','", range(0,9)) . "')";
```

You can see the results of the `implode()` & `range()` at [this codepad](http://codepad.org/Yjn097Je).

Comment: I will give this a try, though what I have above is based on what I have seen in drupal variable dumps.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working, the query has changed when I do a dump after my changes, but within the function. Don't think it is being used though.

Answer (score 0):

since you want to select all the content titles that start with a number why not just put something like

```
ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(node.title, 1, 1))
```

or

```
BETWEEN 0 - 9
```

in you WHERE statement.

Comment: I have tried these today also and had no luck with them. Thanks for the input though.